# This bucket name is already in use. Bucket names must be globally unique. Try another name.

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In google cloud storage, I'm trying to create a bucket with name "www.coladmmo.com" but it says "This bucket name is already in use. Bucket names must be globally unique. Try another name. " I only created this bucket with this name successfully before and i deleted the entire project. But now it says that it is already in use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Storage 'static' bucketname not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127112/google-cloud-storage-static-bucketname-not-available)

Answer (score 2):

The bucket probably still exists in the project you deleted. See the [Create, shut down, and restore projects](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787) documentation page, specifically:

> After a 30-day waiting period, the project and associated data are
>   permanently deleted from the console.
>
> Note that after the 30-day waiting period ends, the time it takes to
>   completely delete a project may vary. For example, if a project has
>   billing set up, it might not be completely deleted until the current
>   billing cycle ends, you receive the next bill, and your account is
>   successfully charged. Additionally, the number and types of services
>   in use may also affect when the system permanently deletes a project.